# Grails + Docker

Tags: docker, grails, azure-devops

I have a simple grails4 project with two controllers and default dependancies. When I try to use Azure Web App or Azure DevOps with my Docker Container it fails with the below error:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at grails.init.Start.main(Start.java:85)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not determine grails version due to missing properties file
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.invoke(CachedConstructor.java:83)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ConstructorSite$ConstructorSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.callConstructor(ConstructorSite.java:105)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallConstructor(CallSiteArray.java:59)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:237)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:249)
at grails.init.RunCommand.main(RunCommand.groovy:21)
```

My docker file looks like this...

```
FROM openjdk:8u151-jdk-alpine
MAINTAINER Michael J. Lee "*****@****.com"

EXPOSE 8080

WORKDIR /app
COPY *.jar application.jar

CMD ["java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-jar","/app/application.jar"]
```

Everything else is stock grails.

Comment: Just a quick glance at grails-core I do not see the package `grails.init` or can find the text to that runtime description - you may have something else going on here.

Answer (score 1):

The error says "Could not determine grails version due to missing properties file". You might need add the gradle.properties file in your app.

You can create the gradle.properties file in your app root dir with below example contents

```
grailsVersion=4.0.1
gormVersion=6.0.12.RELEASE
grailsWrapperVersion=3.4.1
```

Please refer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44821414/grails-3-could-not-determine-grails-wrapper-version-due-to-missing-gradle-prop)

Comment: Could you share your build pipeline? I created a simple test grails project and using your dockerfile. The build succeeded.

Comment: This is actually working now, strangely it worked when I used the gradle wrapper over grails.